# Why ruby substracts wrongly 2.47-1.56?

Tags: ruby

Why ruby substracts 2.47-1.56 like this

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> 2.47 - 1.56
=> 0.9100000000000001
```

instead like this

```
0.91
```

How can I get right answer?

Comment: try rounding off

Comment: It's a feature, not a bug. It's due to how floating point arithmetic works. See [this video by Tom Scott/Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0). If you need exact operation of decimal numbers (like is needed for money) **do NOT** use floating point (i.e. decimal numbers), use integers. (For your particular case, you would need to do 247-156, then manually divide the answer by 100).

Comment: Try `0.1 + 0.2` and be amazed!

Comment: `(2.47r - 1.56r).to_f`, converting to float as late as you can.

Comment: You might want to use a so-called [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library. In Ruby that’s [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/BigDecimal.html). As opposed to floats, it can store all numbers with a finite decimal presentation exactly.

Comment: For me it's a bug not a feature, because it answer not expected answer. lua does job good.

Comment: @somenxavier Lua also uses the same floats as Ruby. See this example: https://ideone.com/LjPb5H The fact that Lua outputs different numbers identically by default makes it kind of worse in my opinion.

Comment: I'd say it is neither a bug nor a feature, it is merely an innate property of floating point arithmetic. [0.30000000000000004.com](https://0.30000000000000004.com/) provides a list of examples in many popular and esoteric languages.

Comment: No, it's not "innate" property: $0.1 + 0.2 = 1 * 10^{-1} + 2 * 10^{-1} = 3 * 10^{-1} = 0.3$. If most programming languages and IEEE spec are wrong is not user fault. Why my calculator states 0.3 and a very expensive machine states something wrong. Think just as user perspective.

Comment: @somenxavier as a "user" you can use your computer's calculator and it will most likely show the correct result. As a developer (e.g. when implementing a calculator yourself), it's your job to pick the right tool. Floats are versatile and fast and they do have many applications. But they come with restrictions and are of limited use for exact calculations, hence the warning in the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Float.html): _"Floating point has a different arithmetic and is an inexact number. So you should know its esoteric system."_.